# Problems with ArrayList and file transfer

Tags: java, arraylist, file-transfer

I'm creating a TFTP server. I've got it tranfering files fine but most of the files wont open when they arrive at the other end. This is because the output of the ArrayList im using to store file bytes from every packet received adds a load of bytes to the start of the file. eg. "¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w   ur [B¬óøTà  xp  ü!". The reason for using the List in the first place is that the server im creating has no way to tell the file size of the file which is being received. Therefore as far as I can tell I cant use a byte[] as this needs to be initialised with a set length. Is there any way round this?

```
            WRQ WRQ = new WRQ();
            ACK ACK = new ACK();
            DatagramPacket outPacket;
            byte[] bytes;
            byte[] fileOut;
            List fileBytes = new ArrayList();
            outPacket = WRQ.firstPacket(packet);
            socket.send(outPacket);

            socket.receive(packet);

            while (packet.getLength() == 516){

            bytes = WRQ.doWRQ(packet);
            fileBytes.add(bytes);

            outPacket = ACK.doACK(packet);
            socket.send(outPacket);

            socket.receive(packet); 

            }

            bytes = WRQ.doWRQ(packet);
            fileBytes.add(bytes);

            outPacket = ACK.doACK(packet);
            socket.send(outPacket);

            ObjectOutputStream os;

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(5000);
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(byteStream));
            os.flush();
            os.writeObject(fileBytes);
            os.flush();
            byte[] outFile = byteStream.toByteArray();
            os.close();

            FileOutputStream foStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            foStream.write(outFile);
            foStream.close();
```

Comment: Code please. Looks like you have just (default-)serialized the `ArrayList` into a file.

Comment: Exactly how are you writing the data? Serializing the arraylist using writeObject? Have to write the bytes not the arraylist.

Comment: Have you verified that the server has the correct bytes in its `ArrayList`?  If so, you probably just need to change the method you are using to write to the destination file.

Comment: Code in post edit above. I am just using write. how do I just write bytes?

Comment: You are not using just write, you are using writeObject() (Serializing). Instead of adding the bytes to a List, write them on the OutputStream.

Answer (score 4):

You store byte arrays in an ArrayList, and then you write the whole ArrayList to a ByteArrayOutputStream wrapped in an ObjectOutputStream, using the `writeObject()` method.

This uses the native Object serialization mechanism to save the ArrayList object. It doesn't write every byte array in the list one after the other. To make it clear: it writes the class name, and the internal structure of the ArrayList, using the object serialization protocol.

You don't need an ArrayList. Write directly to a ByteArrayOutputStream, or even directly to a FileOutputStream. As is, you're trying to

- write bytes to a list
- write the bytes in the list to a byte array
- write the byte array to a file.

It would be much more straightforward (and efficient) to write directly to the output file (wrapped in a BufferedOutputStream for buffering)

Comment: This sounds like it would fix everything. Can you help me out a little bit with putting this into code?

Comment: You have nearly everything in your code already. And you'll learn more if you do it yourself than if I do it for you.

Comment: Definately I understand that. I was asking for pointers on how to put it into code as I've tried using BufferedOutputStream.write() in the while loop and then after it. It saves the file but with absolutely nothing in it.